# Error in subscribe(Consumer<Object>) reactor

Tags: project-reactor

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Flux.just(1,2,3)
                .onErrorContinue((err,i)-> System.out.println(err+" "+i))
                .subscribe(i->{
                    System.out.println(10/(2-i));
                }, System.out::println);
    }
```

error is generated inside the consumer function, how to handle such errors without canceling the subscription.

Output:

```
10
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

That last subscription is the last step in the whole pipeline, but indeed in recent versions of Reactor the lambda-based subscriber will catch exceptions in the `onNext` handler and propagate them to the `onError` handler, which implies cancellation. That is the best default choice the library can make.

If you don't want that, then you need to add try/catch in your `onNext` handler, that's it.